# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

This error is thrown a lot, but I can't find the solution. I am new to the Entity Framework and in my first approach I got this error.

Error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

My Code :-

```
foreach (interest _interest in inList)
{
   _interest.schemeId = _scheme.id;
   _interest.schemeSubId = _schemeLoan.id;
    db.interests.AddObject(_interest);
}
```

Comment: You really have to show more code. Where does `inList` come from? How many context instances are involved? This error occurs when an object from one context is added to an other context.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you aren't getting rid of another context you have and this particular object already exists as belonging to another instance of your context ie db. Make sure you dispose your context objects *after every request* and that you arent using two contexts erroneously in your code.